# ExpressJS require Javascript prototyped object in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype-programming

I have a file that looks like this:

```
function UserController(){};

UserController.prototype = {
    theData: [],
    findAll: function(callback) {
        callback( null, this.theData );
     },
    findByID: function(id, callback) {
        var result = null;
        var count = theData.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.theData[i]._id == id) {
                result = this.theData[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        callback(null, result);
    },
    findByName: function(name, callback) {
        var result = null;
        var count = theData.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (this.theData[i].name == name) {
                result = this.theData[i];
                break;
            }
        };

        callback(null, result);
    },
    save: function(users, callback) {
        var user = null;

        if(typeof(users.length) === 'undefined') {
            users = [users];
        }

        var count = users.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            user = users[i];
            user._id = userCounter++;
            user.created_at = new Date();
        };

        callback(null, users);
    }
};
```

When I inspect the object (based off [this](http://codeinthehole.com/archives/12-Inspecting-Javascript-objects.html)), it tells me that it `is function UserController(){}` and has no methods or properties.

I've never used prototyping in Javascript and I can't see a thing wrong with what I've done here.  It should be noted that I'm using this with Node.js and Expressjs but I don't believe that would be causing this problem.

**EDIT**
For brevity's sake I only posted what I was currently using, but I have also had the exact same problem using the file like this:

```
var userCounter = 1;

function UserController(){};

UserController.prototype.theData = [];

UserController.prototype.findAll = function(callback) {
    callback( null, this.theData );
};

UserController.prototype.findByID = function(id, callback) {
    var result = null;
    var count = theData.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (this.theData[i]._id == id)
        {
            result = this.theData[i];
            break;
        }
    };

    callback(null, result);
};

UserController.prototype.findByName = function(name, callback) {
    var result = null;
    var count = theData.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (this.theData[i].name == name) {
            result = this.theData[i];
            break;
        }
    };

    callback(null, result);
};

UserController.prototype.save = function(users, callback) {
    var user = null;

    if(typeof(users.length) === 'undefined') {
        users = [users];
    }

    var count = users.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        user = users[i];
        user._id = userCounter++;
        user.created_at = new Date();
    };

    callback(null, users);
};
```

**One more edit**
If I put this in the same file and Inspect it I get the results I would expect:

```
function Test(){};

Test.prototype = {
  theData: [],
  hello: function(){
    return "Hello World!";
  }
};
```

I don't see the difference and I don't see an error in my UserController code.

Comment: I wonder if your problem is that your first part is a function, then you are adding functions in a way that I usually do for adding functions to objects.  You may want to follow this and see if it helps: http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm

Comment: Have you actually run the code and tried to call methods? Don't believe every output.

Comment: @James Black: That is normal prototype inheritance. There is actually nothing wrong with the code. The prototope of a function is actually an object.

Comment: @James Black: I'm updating the question in a minute to address what you said.   @Felix: Yes I have run the code and it says there is no method 'findByName'.

Comment: @James P.: Could you please post how you call that function?

Comment: Can you post an example of how you instantiate your object and try to call the method(s)?

Comment: How about you don't use `prototype`? I did a quick test and appending each property directly to the function works. `UserController.something="something else"`

Comment: @JCOC611: That will achieve something different and is not related to prototypal inheritance anymore...

Comment: I was declaring UserController like this `var UserController = require('./user-controller').UserController;` which from what I understand is how you do it in Expressjs....of course, since I said in my question that Expressjs probably isn't the problem...it looks like it IS the problem.  If I put the UserController code in the same file and Inspect it, it works fine...so now I have to go figure out the Expressjs `require` method.

Comment: Side note:  `if(typeof(users.length) === 'undefined') {` in the `save` method will give you an error.

Comment: @Felix: What should it be then?

Comment: Oh sorry... I confused `users` with `user`. It should be alright! NVM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html) helped me figure it out.

Turns out it WAS a problem with Expressjs.  When using another file, you have to specifically call `export` on methods and objects you want to use with `require`.  Or alternately, you can just call `this.blahblah = function(){};` instead of `export`.  Then when you `require` a file, it automatically turns it into an object.

**EDIT**
I found a different solution.  It was as simple as changing my `require` call to look like this: `var userController = new (require('./controllers/user').UserController);`
After that, I can use Prototyped functions and objects just fine which makes the file much more readable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `UserController` is a function.  Does it have properties?  Yes, it has two properties, namely `length` and `prototype`.  All functions in JavaScript have these two properties.  Why don't you see these properties?  Because they are not enumerable properties.  Properties in JavaScript can have one or more attributes.  In ES3 they are ReadOnly, DontEnum, and DontDelete.  In ES5 they are configurable, writable, enumerable, get, set, and value.

In either version, `length` and `prototype` are not enumerable, so your inspector will not show them to you.

Incidentally all the "methods" you wrote are properties of the object `UserController.prototype`, not `UserController`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the Inspect code I used actually takes prototype into effect I believe (or at least I know that it output what I expected on my "Test()" object.

Comment: So does your inspector say that the object `Test` has two properties or zero?